# ST32WL RF Matching Network

Tags: rf, stm32, schematics, impedance-matching, iot

I am adapting a minimal design based on the [TTN Generic Node](https://github.com/TheThingsIndustries/generic-node-se). I am trying to reduce the BOM and do not require the option to switch power. In the following diagram there are 4 RF signal I/O pins, 2 for RX and 2 for TX:

RFI_P: Positive differential input (RX+, 100Ω).

RFI_N: Negative differential input (RX-, 100Ω).

RFO_HP: Low power output (TX, 50Ω).

RFO_LP: High power output (TX, 50Ω).

There is an internal "power amplifier" supplying from pin VR_PA.

These all feed into a matching circuit that has two switches(U6B and U7).

[image]

If I remove the switches and thus circuitry marked in red highlighter, would this have any impact on the performance of the circuit?